# I can't see the page of my Test Module in Prestashop

Tags: php, module, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm following the manual for know who can be create modules for Prestashop (this is the link [prestashop developer](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Displaying+content+on+the+front-office)).
All works (I can configure my module and move to the Left Column) but I've a problem when I click in my href always see "Error 404 : the page not exists".

I read the documentation and I didn't found some mistakes in my code: I put the files display.php and display.tpl in the module root folder.

My code for display.php is:

```
class mymoduledisplayModuleFrontController extends ModuleFrontController{
  public function initContent(){
    parent::initContent();
    $this->setTemplate('display.tpl');
  }
}
```

And the code for display.tpl is:

```
<h4>Hi!!!!!</h4>
```

What can be my mistake? I didn't found!

Thanks so much for the help

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know `display.php` should be in `/controllers/front` folder of the module's main folder. so you should have 2 `display.php` files:

1. in root folder with module configuration & hooks display with something like that:

```
public function hookDisplayLeftColumn($params)
{
  $this->context->smarty->assign(
      array(
          'my_module_name' => Configuration::get('MYMODULE_NAME'),
          'my_module_link' => $this->context->link->getModuleLink('mymodule', 'display')
      )
  );
  return $this->display(__FILE__, 'mymodule.tpl');
}
```

2. in controllers/front of your modules main folder for displaying in main content.

```
class mymoduledisplayModuleFrontController extends ModuleFrontController
{
  public function initContent()
  {
    parent::initContent();
    $this->setTemplate('display.tpl');
  }
}
```

Read the docs more carefully. it's all in here!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to create your display file inside a controller (controllers/front/display.php) the content of the file should be something like

```
class MyModuleDisplayModuleFrontController extends ModuleFrontController
{
    public function initContent()
    {
        parent::initContent();
        //do some stuff
   }   
}
```